# Regular expression for 10 digit number without any special characters  

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What is the regular expression for a 10 digit numeric number (no special characters and no decimal).

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use this regular expression to match ten digits only:

```
@"^\d{10}$"
```

To find a sequence of ten consecutive digits anywhere in a string, use:

```
@"\d{10}"
```

Note that this will also find the first 10 digits of an 11 digit number. To search anywhere in the string for *exactly* 10 consecutive digits and not more you can use negative [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)"
```

Comment: Sorry for nubiness, but what's a "negative lookaround"?

Comment: @sova: You can read about lookaround assertions here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html. The expression means 10 digits without a digit before - `(?<!\d)`, and without a digit after - `(?!\d)`.

Answer (score 11):

Use the following pattern.

```
^\d{10}$
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:
only 10 digit number is accepted.

```
^[0-9]{10}$
```

Answer (score 6):

An example of how to implement it:

```
public bool ValidateSocialSecNumber(string socialSecNumber)
{
    //Accepts only 10 digits, no more no less. (Like Mike's answer)
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"(?<!\d)\d{10}(?!\d)");

    if(pattern.isMatch(socialSecNumber))
    {
        //Do something
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You could've also done it in another way by e.g. using `Match` and then wrapping a try-catch block around the pattern matching. However, if a wrong input is given quite often, it's quite expensive to throw an exception. Thus, I prefer the above way, in simple cases at least.

Answer (score 5):

```
\d{10}
```

I believe that should do it

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
\d{10}
```

I hope it helps.