# Replacing whole values within a string

Tags: .net, regex

I have a string which contains some ids, basically a sql expression within a string. I need to present it to user in a more friendly manner ie. Replace ids with names from the database. The problem is that some ids are single digits and others are 2 digits. So when I search and replace a single digit, it also replaces *part of* 2 digit strings. For example, if the original string is:

```
    id not in (2, 3, 4) and id > 22
```

when I perform a search and replace for `2`, both the the numbers `2` and `22` get replaced.

With a regex I can find `2`, but when I replace it (regex expression basically looks for number that I want and some possible delimiters like space `,()` and such). Is it possible to replace this number but keep those delimiters?

This is what I have now:

```
Regex.Replace(returnValue
               , String.Format("[,( )]{0}[,( )]", number)
               , replaceValue)
```

Comment: I have to ask why would you even want to do this?

Comment: I need to save an expression that i will use later for filtering data, and i need to be able to display it to user in as friendly manner as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern suggested by **I4V** looks simplest and great to me but you can also try this pattern:

```
(\d+)(?=[,\)])
```

The idea behind this pattern is that, sometimes we have numbers in `column names` like `Address1`, `Address2` so using that will match with them as well. This pattern will not allow these cases.

Hope it will help!

**EDIT**

```
List<int> replacements = new List<int>(new int[] { 5 , 6 , 7});
string input = "id not in (2, 3, 4) and id > 22";

foreach(int element in replacements)
   input = Regex.Replace(input,@"(\d+)(?=[,\)])",element.ToString());
```

Here:

ID 2 will be replaced by 5, 3 will be replaced by 6 and 4 will be replaced by 7. so finall string would look like:

```
id not in (5, 6, 7) and id > 22
```

Comment: this helped, i tweaked my code and the expression that gets parsed so i am able to use easier parsing and with these examples i made something that works (so far)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
string input = "id not in (2, 3, 4) and id > 22";
var newstr = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", m => GetUserName(m.Value));


string GetUserName(string s)
{
    return ">>" + s  + "<<";
}
```

Comment: @Bidou you can do whatever you want in `GetUserName`. even return the original string. `GetUserName` doesn't have to be one line code.

Comment: What I meant was that your Regex will match the number 22, which is not what the OP wanted (if I understood the question well)

Comment: Same for me (if I understood the question well). But what I say, even if the regex matches you don't have to replace it. Add this line to `GetUserName` for ex, `if(s.Length==2) return s;`

Comment: exactly, the problem now i have is that i have values 2, 22 and 222 and i need to replace only 2 (those are ids). i created regex that matches only 2 but it eats preceding and char after it when replacing

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to user look ahead and look behind - so your pattern looks like this

```
"(?<=[^0-9]){0}(?=[^0-9])"
```

Or if you like your code example

```
Regex.Replace(returnValue
    , String.Format("(?<=[^0-9]){0}(?=[^0-9])", number)
    , replaceValue)
```

So we're saying:

`(?<=[^0-9])` look behind our matched item and make sure it isn't an integer

`{0}` the matched item

`(?=[^0-9])` look ahead of our matched item and make sure it isn't an integer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use negative lookarounds as explained here: [Regular expression for 10 digit number without any special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685500/regular-expression-for-10-digit-number-without-any-special-characters)

For your example:

```
const string input = "id not in (2, 3, 4) and id > 22";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!\d)(\d{1})(?!\d)", @"--$1--");
```

And the result:

"id not in (--2--, --3--, --4--) and id > 22"

Comment: Have you checked it against: `id not in (25, 26, 27) and id > 237`

Comment: It seems that I misunderstood the question. I thought that the goal was to match only numbers that contain one digit. The example in the question (with 2 and 22) mislead me...

Comment: the goal was to match the exact number, and not the numbers that contain it, so 22 and 2222 would pose the same problem. my idea was regex that matches the number i want and checks if a nondigit char was before and after