# A way to extract all the numbers who have 10 digits from a web site?

Tags: php

I have a task to extract some numbers from a list of websites. All these numbers have the same number of digits like 1234567890.

How can I extract all the numbers that have 10 digits from a specific url using PHP ?

Comment: http://php.net/preg_match

Comment: preg_match_all with '/\d{10}/'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685500/regular-expression-for-10-digit-number-without-any-special-characters

Answer (score 1):

Using [regexp](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) with negative [look ahead and look behind](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) expressions:

- `(?<!\d)` - Not prefixed by number
- `\d{10}` - 10 numbers
- `(?!\d)` - Not suffixed by number

And apply with [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('~(?<!\\d)(\\d){10}(!?\\d)~', $html, $matches);
foreach( $matches[1] as $match){
   var_dump($match);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
$sites = array(        
        'http://foo.bar/',        
        'http://blah.baz/'        
);

foreach ($sites as $site) {        
        $ch = curl_init($site);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);        

        $res = curl_exec($ch);        

        if ($res === false) {        
                echo "Failed to download $site: " . curl_error($ch) . "\n";        
        } else {        
                if (preg_match_all('/\d{10}/', $res, $matches) !== false) {        
                        echo "Found some numbers at $site\n";        
                        foreach ($matches as $match) {        
                                echo "Found number: " . $match[0] . "\n";        
                        }
                }
        }

        curl_close($ch);        
}
?>
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question...