# Regular expression validator for 10 digit and numbers only c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

i want a regular expression validator that will have numbers only till 10 digits

i have tried this but it is for only numbers and not for numbers of digit

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvDigits" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobId"
                                ErrorMessage="Enter numbers only till 10 digit" ValidationGroup="valGroup" ForeColor="Red"
                                ValidationExpression="\d+" />
```

Comment: if you need a range up to 10 digits `\d{1,10}`

Comment: Possibe Duplicate [Regular expression for 10 digit number without any special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685500/regular-expression-for-10-digit-number-without-any-special-characters)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use a [***limiting quantifier* `{min,max}`**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit).

If you allow empty input, use `{0,10}` to match 0 to 10 digits:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{0,10}$"
```

Else, use `{1,10}` to allow 1 to 10 digits:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{1,10}$"
```

Or to match *exactly* 10-digit strings omit the `min,` part:

```
ValidationExpression="^[0-9]{10}$"
```

Also, note that server-side validation uses .NET regex syntax, and `\d` matches more than digits from `0` to `9` in this regex flavor, thus prefer `[0-9]`. See [*`\d` is less efficient than `[0-9]`*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16621738/3832970).

Besides, it seems you can omit `^` and `$` altogether (see [MSDN *Regular Expressions in ASP.NET* article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx)):

> You do not need to specify beginning of string and end of string matching characters (`^` and `$`)—they are assumed. **If you add them, it won't hurt (or change) anything—it's simply unnecessary.**

Most people prefer to keep them explicit inside the pattern for clarity.

Comment: My reading is the OP wants exactly 10 digits. You might want to include that in your answer too...

Comment: @Chris: I see *only **till** 10 digits*. I guess from ... till... ? Well, I added that case to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, its not exactly clear. My reading is "input numbers until you have 10 digits". The title also suggests 10 digits (and not less). Anyway, you've added it now. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Test this answer:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rvDigits" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtMobId" ErrorMessage="Enter numbers only till 10 digit" ValidationGroup="valGroup" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="[0-9]{10}" />
```