# Asp .NET MVC Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I want to validate my model to accept only 10 numbers and the number **should not** start with `700`.
Any idea how can I do it using data annotation?

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required ")]
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = " CR should be 10 digits")]
public string CR_Number { get; set; }
```

Comment: Try: `^(?!700)\d{10}$`

Comment: refer this link [regular expression for accepting 10 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685500/regular-expression-for-10-digit-number-without-any-special-characters)

Comment: refer this link [accepting 10 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685500/regular-expression-for-10-digit-number-without-any-special-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required ")]
 [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = " CR should be 10 digits")]
 [RegularExpression("^(?!700)\d", ErrorMessage = "CR should not start with 700.")]
 public string CR_Number { get; set; }
```

Or you can merge the last two as suggested in the comments "^(?!700)\d{10}$".

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I make it starts with 700 and accept only 10 digits?

Comment: ^(700)([0-9]{7})$